# How do I create a line graph in Python using Pandas for the number of times something occurs in a year?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that describes the visits at a veterinarian office. Each row of data corresponds to one visit. One column is year. How do I plot a line graph with y being the amount of visits and x being the year?

```
df.plot.line(x, "year")
```

I am having trouble assigning x as the number of visits per year.

Answer (score 0):

Import pyplot, and plot the columns as so:

**example df:**

```
>>> df
   visits  Year
0      13  2010
1      18  2011
2      16  2012
3       7  2013
4       9  2014
5      11  2015
6      19  2016
7      12  2017
8       4  2018
9      19  2019
```

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df[['visits','Year']].plot.line(x='Year',y='visits')
plt.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image]